# Is Jquery enough for Contact Form validation?

Tags: php, jquery

I don't want to use any Jquery plugins like Jquery-Validation.
I want to use only Jquery to validate Contact Form in my website.

My question is if the only Jquery validation code is enough, or I should add php code.
My form has Name, Email, and Message.
My concern is the Email field.
I validated like below;

```
   function check_email() {
       var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)   ((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-   \uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-  \uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-  \uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
   //return pattern.test(emailText);
       if(pattern.test($("#email").val())) {
           $("#email_err_msg").hide();
       } else {
           $("#email_err_msg").html("*Invalid email address.");
            $("#email_err_msg").show();
           err_email = true;
       }

   }
```

Is this enough, or do I need php code too?

Thanks

Comment: That's a hefty regular expression you've got there...

Comment: You shouldn't rely on front-end validation only, since it's easily circumvented by someone who knows what they're doing JS wise. Back-end is a harder to get around, but for the best approach, use both.

Comment: Categorically no. What happens when you turn of JavaScript in the browser

Comment: Also, if you're planning on validating email with a regex, [have a read of this first](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).  It's not trivial...

Comment: Does that regex actually work? \uFDF0-\uFFEF is not correct ...

Comment: For me one reason to use PHP for this beside back-end scripting is the `regEx` PHP has a simple function for this `filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` combined with `$.ajax()` `filter_var` http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php, `$.ajax()`
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **always** should have backend validation as frontend validation can always be manipulated (or even removed)

There is a golden rule of never trust anything that is submitted from the browser.

Comment: Thank you all. I will add php validation too.